# Integrating Creative Tim's Material Kit Pro React frontend with React-Redux-Firebase generator backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to integrate Creative Tim's Material Kit Pro React frontend with the generator for the backend provided [here](https://github.com/prescottprue/generator-react-firebase)

I generated a material ui react app using the back end yo generator. I then installed the additional dependencies specified in the Creative Tim file. At that point, I get an error. SCSS files that previously loaded in the original app now throw an error that says:

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./LoadingSpinner.scss"
    at webpackMissingModule (LoadingSpinner.js:4)

I have copied both webpack.config.js files but they are so different, I can't get a grip on where to start integrating them.

Has anyone tried to use both packages?

Material Kit Pro React webpack.config.js has:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.test'});
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.development'});
}

module.exports =  (env) => {
  const isProduction = env ==='production';
  const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');
  return {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    // resolve: { alias: { Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets') } },
    module: {
      rules: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }, {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: CSSExtract.extract({
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }
          ]
        })
      }]
    },
    plugins: [
      CSSExtract,
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY),
        'process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN': JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN),
        'process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL),
        'process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID),
        'process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET': JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET),
        'process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID)
      })
    ],

    devtool: isProduction ?  'source-map' : 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      historyApiFallback: true,
      publicPath: '/dist/'
    }

  };
};
```

Backend generator has:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const project = require('../project.config')

const inProject = path.resolve.bind(path, project.basePath)
const inProjectSrc = file => inProject(project.srcDir, file)

const __DEV__ = project.env === 'development'
const __TEST__ = project.env === 'test'
const __PROD__ = project.env === 'production'

const config = {
  entry: {
    normalize: [inProjectSrc('normalize')],
    main: [inProjectSrc(project.main)]
  },
  devtool: project.sourcemaps ? 'source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: inProject(project.outDir),
    filename: __DEV__ ? '[name].js' : '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: project.publicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [inProject(project.srcDir), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  externals: project.externals,
  module: {
    rules: []
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(
      Object.assign(
        {
          'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(project.env) },
          __DEV__,
          __TEST__,
          __PROD__
        },
        project.globals
      )
    )
  ],
  node: {
    // disable node constants so constants.js file is used instead (see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/)
    constants: false
  }
}

// JavaScript
// ------------------------------------
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude: [
    /node_modules/,
    /redux-firestore\/es/,
    /react-redux-firebase\/es/
    // Add other packages that you are npm linking here
  ],
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        // ignore root .babelrc (Check issue #59 for more details)
        babelrc: false,

        plugins: [
          'lodash',
          'transform-decorators-legacy',
          'babel-plugin-transform-class-properties',
          'babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
          'babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions',
          [
            'babel-plugin-transform-runtime',
            {
              helpers: true,
              polyfill: false, // we polyfill needed features in src/normalize.js
              regenerator: true
            }
          ],
          [
            'babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread',
            {
              useBuiltIns: true // we polyfill Object.assign in src/normalize.js
            }
          ]
        ],
        presets: [
          'babel-preset-react',
          [
            'babel-preset-env',
            {
              targets: {
                ie9: true,
                uglify: true,
                modules: false
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})

// Styles
// ------------------------------------
const extractStyles = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'styles/[name].[contenthash].css',
  allChunks: true,
  disable: __DEV__
})

config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
  loader: extractStyles.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: project.sourcemaps,
          modules: true,
          importLoaders: 2,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          minimize: {
            autoprefixer: {
              add: true,
              remove: true,
              browsers: ['last 2 versions']
            },
            discardComments: {
              removeAll: true
            },
            discardUnused: false,
            mergeIdents: false,
            reduceIdents: false,
            safe: true,
            sourcemap: project.sourcemaps
          }
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: project.sourcemaps,
          includePaths: [inProjectSrc('styles')]
        }
      }
    ]
  })
})
config.plugins.push(extractStyles)

// Images
// ------------------------------------
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options: {
    limit: 8192
  }
})

// Fonts
// ------------------------------------
;[
  ['woff', 'application/font-woff'],
  ['woff2', 'application/font-woff2'],
  ['otf', 'font/opentype'],
  ['ttf', 'application/octet-stream'],
  ['eot', 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject'],
  ['svg', 'image/svg+xml']
].forEach(font => {
  const extension = font[0]
  const mimetype = font[1]

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: new RegExp(`\\.${extension}$`),
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
      limit: 10000,
      mimetype
    }
  })
})

// HTML Template
// ------------------------------------
config.plugins.push(
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: inProjectSrc('index.html'),
    inject: true,
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }
  })
)

// Development Tools
// ------------------------------------
if (__DEV__) {
  config.entry.main.push(
    `webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?path=${
      config.output.publicPath
    }__webpack_hmr`
  )
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
  )
}

// Bundle Splitting
// ------------------------------------
if (!__TEST__) {
  const bundles = ['normalize', 'manifest']

  if (project.vendors && project.vendors.length) {
    bundles.unshift('vendor')
    config.entry.vendor = project.vendors
  }
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ names: bundles })
  )
}

// Production Optimizations
// ------------------------------------
if (__PROD__) {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: false
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: !!config.devtool,
      comments: false,
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true,
        conditionals: true,
        unused: true,
        comparisons: true,
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        evaluate: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true
      }
    })
  )
}

module.exports = config
```

I can see the css loaders are different, but I can't see what to do to make the Creative Tim files work with this backend. Has anyone figured this out?

I have tried adding tests to the module exports statement in the generator so that it reads as follows:

```
module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [{
          loader: "style-loader"
      }, {
          loader: "css-loader"
      }, {
          loader: "sass-loader",
          // options: {
          //     includePaths: ["absolute/path/a", "absolute/path/b"]
          // }
      }],
    }],  
  },
```

That attempt produces a new error that reads:

```
web.dom.iterable.js:19 Uncaught Error: Module build failed: 
@import 'base';
^
      Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
```

I also tried adding style-loader as an additional loader to the webpack.config file (alongside css-loader and sass-loader), but that produces the following error:

```
      Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"

(line 1, column 1)
    at Object../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/loader.js??ref--2-0!./node_modules/style-loader/index.js!./node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--2-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--2-
```

Others who have had problems getting the css configured suggest that there may be config defined elsewhere. I don't seem to have that. I am about halfway through deleting all the references to css in the backend generated file. That was working (up to newProjectTile) but now that still generates failure to build css error.

Driving me crazy that config is so complicated across these tools. If anyone has added a custom theme to the backend generator (regardless of whether it's the Creative Tim theme or otherwise), have you found a way to compile CSS? Any tips would be very much appreciated.

Currently, my webpack.config file is as follows - errors galore in the console and still no closer to an idea for how to resolve them.

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const project = require('../project.config')

const inProject = path.resolve.bind(path, project.basePath)
const inProjectSrc = file => inProject(project.srcDir, file)

const __DEV__ = project.env === 'development'
const __TEST__ = project.env === 'test'
const __PROD__ = project.env === 'production'
const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');


const config = {
  entry: {
    normalize: [inProjectSrc('normalize')],
    main: [inProjectSrc(project.main)]
  },
  devtool: project.sourcemaps ? 'source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: inProject(project.outDir),
    filename: __DEV__ ? '[name].js' : '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: project.publicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [inProject(project.srcDir), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  externals: project.externals,
  module: {
    rules: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      use: CSSExtract.extract({
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },

          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      })
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    CSSExtract,
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(
      Object.assign(
        {
          'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(project.env) },
          __DEV__,
          __TEST__,
          __PROD__
        },
        project.globals
      )
    )
  ],
  node: {
    // disable node constants so constants.js file is used instead (see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/)
    constants: false
  }
}

// JavaScript
// ------------------------------------
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude: [
    /node_modules/,
    /redux-firestore\/es/,
    /react-redux-firebase\/es/
    // Add other packages that you are npm linking here
  ],
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        // ignore root .babelrc (Check issue #59 for more details)
        babelrc: false,

        plugins: [
          'lodash',
          'transform-decorators-legacy',
          'babel-plugin-transform-class-properties',
          'babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
          'babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions',
          [
            'babel-plugin-transform-runtime',
            {
              helpers: true,
              polyfill: false, // we polyfill needed features in src/normalize.js
              regenerator: true
            }
          ],
          [
            'babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread',
            {
              useBuiltIns: true // we polyfill Object.assign in src/normalize.js
            }
          ]
        ],
        presets: [
          'babel-preset-react',
          [
            'babel-preset-env',
            {
              targets: {
                ie9: true,
                uglify: true,
                modules: false
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})

// Styles
// ------------------------------------
const extractStyles = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'styles/[name].[contenthash].css',
  allChunks: true,
  disable: __DEV__
})

config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
  loader: extractStyles.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: project.sourcemaps,
          modules: true,
          importLoaders: 2,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          minimize: {
            autoprefixer: {
              add: true,
              remove: true,
              browsers: ['last 2 versions']
            },
            discardComments: {
              removeAll: true
            },
            discardUnused: false,
            mergeIdents: false,
            reduceIdents: false,
            safe: true,
            sourcemap: project.sourcemaps
          }
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'style-loader'
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: project.sourcemaps,
          includePaths: [inProjectSrc('styles')]
        }
      }
    ]
  })
})
config.plugins.push(extractStyles)

// Images
// ------------------------------------
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options: {
    limit: 8192
  }
})

// Fonts
// ------------------------------------
;[
  ['woff', 'application/font-woff'],
  ['woff2', 'application/font-woff2'],
  ['otf', 'font/opentype'],
  ['ttf', 'application/octet-stream'],
  ['eot', 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject'],
  ['svg', 'image/svg+xml']
].forEach(font => {
  const extension = font[0]
  const mimetype = font[1]

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: new RegExp(`\\.${extension}$`),
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
      limit: 10000,
      mimetype
    }
  })
})

// HTML Template
// ------------------------------------
config.plugins.push(
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: inProjectSrc('index.html'),
    inject: true,
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }
  })
)

// Development Tools
// ------------------------------------
if (__DEV__) {
  config.entry.main.push(
    `webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?path=${
      config.output.publicPath
    }__webpack_hmr`
  )
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
  )
}

// Bundle Splitting
// ------------------------------------
if (!__TEST__) {
  const bundles = ['normalize', 'manifest']

  if (project.vendors && project.vendors.length) {
    bundles.unshift('vendor')
    config.entry.vendor = project.vendors
  }
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ names: bundles })
  )
}

// Production Optimizations
// ------------------------------------
if (__PROD__) {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: false
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: !!config.devtool,
      comments: false,
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true,
        conditionals: true,
        unused: true,
        comparisons: true,
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        evaluate: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true
      }
    })
  )
}

module.exports = config
```

Comment: have you tried reaching out to creative-tim's team? they usually respond to these kinds of questions.

Comment: Hi @arjayosma - yes I've asked them - I just thought that given its a specific type of integration, others might have tried doing this. They are great with questions.